# create a non-unique ID column, where a new ID is created every time a numeric sequence resets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
product price   date
banana  90  2022-01-01
banana  90  2022-01-02
banana  90  2022-01-03
banana  95  2022-01-04
banana  90  2022-01-05
banana  90  2022-01-06
```

I need to add a non-unique ID column to the table. Every time the price changes, I want the ID to change. This would result in the following table.

```
id  product price   date
A   banana  90  2022-01-01
A   banana  90  2022-01-02
A   banana  90  2022-01-03
B   banana  95  2022-01-04
C   banana  90  2022-01-05
C   banana  90  2022-01-06
```

By searching for answers in SO and Google, I was able to create a column (my_seq) that contains a sequence that resets every time (see sql fiddle for my query) the price changes. But I still don't know how to create an ID column that resets every time the my_seq starts over.

```
my_seq  rn1 rn2 product price   date
1   1   1   banana  90  2022-01-01
2   2   2   banana  90  2022-01-02
3   3   3   banana  90  2022-01-03
1   1   4   banana  95  2022-01-04
1   4   5   banana  90  2022-01-05
2   5   6   banana  90  2022-01-06
```

[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51ded/2) with DDL and my query

thanks

Comment: Are you after a numerical sequence or actually A, B, C etc

Comment: I don't mind being a numerical sequence. The only caveat is that I will group by this ID later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
with cte as (
    select ((lag(price) over w1) <> price)::int changes
         , *
    from my_table
    window w1 as (partition by product order by date) )
select chr( ascii('A') + 
            (sum(coalesce(changes,0)) over w2)::int ) as your_seq
     , product
     , price
     , date
from cte
window w2 as (
  partition by product 
  order by date 
  groups between unbounded preceding and current row);
```

1. The [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) window function references previous row within the same ordered group. It's `null` for the first row, hence the [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) later
2. Result of comparing to the previous price can be cast to `::int`, resulting in `0` for when it's unchanged and `1` where it changed.
3. A [`sum() over (... groups between unbounded preceding and current row)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) is just a rolling sum collecting everything so far, up to the current row in the window. Rolling over `0`'s and `1`'s it'll grow only for rows where the price changed.
4. `chr(ascii(start_char) + offset)` can get you the alphabetical sequence, but it also limits it to alphabet length.

Sample output from a [demo with more tests:](https://dbfiddle.uk/gnuumtmd)

```sql
-- your_seq |  product  | price |    date
------------+-----------+-------+------------
-- A        | apple     |    90 | 2022-01-01
-- A        | apple     |    90 | 2022-01-02
-- A        | apple     |    90 | 2022-01-03
-- B        | apple     |    95 | 2022-01-04
-- C        | apple     |    90 | 2022-01-05
-- C        | apple     |    90 | 2022-01-06
-- A        | banana    |    90 | 2022-01-01
-- A        | banana    |    90 | 2022-01-02
-- A        | banana    |    90 | 2022-01-03
-- B        | banana    |    95 | 2022-01-04
-- C        | banana    |    90 | 2022-01-05
-- C        | banana    |    90 | 2022-01-06
-- A        | orange    |    80 | 2022-01-01
-- A        | papaya    |    20 | 2022-01-01
-- A        | papaya    |    20 | 2022-01-02
-- B        | papaya    |    30 | 2022-01-03
-- A        | pineapple |    40 | 2022-01-01
-- B        | pineapple |    25 | 2022-01-02
-- B        | pineapple |    25 | 2022-01-03
-- A        | satsuma   |    10 | 2022-01-01
-- A        | satsuma   |    10 | 2022-01-02
```

Comment: That's perfect. An alphabetic sequence is not necessary, so I'll just hash the generated numeric sequence.

Comment: Is `groups between unbounded preceding and current row` needed? I'm trying without it and getting similar results

Comment: It's not, that's the [default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS:~:text=The%20default%20framing,the%20current%20row.) behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are half-there already with the query in your Fiddle.

Consider what you get if you subtract your rn1 & rn2 values - you get the values you need to group by.

If you want an increasing sequence you can then apply a dense rank:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() over(order by date)
    - Row_Number() over(partition by product, price order by date) rn
  from my_table
)
select Dense_Rank() over(order by rn) as my_seq,
  product, price, date
from cte;
```

[Modified fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51ded/3)

Answer (score -1):

It will generate sequence number whenever price change.

```
with cte as (
select 
row_number  () over( w) as price_change,

product,price,date
from 
my_table_1
window w as (partition by product,price order by date)
)
select   
product,price,date,
row_number()over(partition by price_change order by price_change) as seq_no
from cte
order by seq_no,price_change
```

output:

```
product|price|date      |seq_no|
-------+-----+----------+------+
banana |   90|2022-01-01|     1|
banana |   90|2022-01-02|     1|
banana |   90|2022-01-03|     1|
banana |   90|2022-01-05|     1|
banana |   90|2022-01-06|     1|
banana |   95|2022-01-04|     2|
```

Comment: instead of sequence no, you want to display alphabet, then use below syntax to get alphabet. CHR(64 + (row_number()over(partition by price_change order by price_change))::INT) as seq_no

Comment: this won't work for me as Day 3 and 5 should have different IDs